# Did the Selay & Antican delegations ever get to the peace process?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

In "TNG : Lonely Among Us" the purpose of the Enterprise's mission was to deliver the Selay and Antican delegations to a peace process. They get side tracked by an energy species from an energy cloud.

**Do they ever get to the the conference? If so do they achieve peace?**

Comment: Why did you remove the season, episode, series, etc. from the title of the question? Do you not want that info in the header? If it's not there, a casual viewer who is scanning for questions might not know what I'm asking about. Is that a policy? @Richard

Comment: I just thought it looked tidier. Generally you include episode details in the body of the question. The tags should advise people what series you're discussing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shooting script would suggest that they did make it to Parliament:

> **PICARD :**           *Riker, with these "peace"          delegates and all, I do need some           rest. Take charge, Number One.*
>
> The "cloud" in far b.g. as WE SEE the Enterprise go into **WARP SPEED EFFECT.**

Obviously they have some destination in mind...

---

And although we don't see them again in the TV show, in the DS9 Young Adult Novel "[Arcade](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/217930.Arcade)", we learn that the peace process did not go well:

> Rotor shrugged. “The Anticans are the mortal enemy of Selay. Honor
> must be defended at all costs.”
>
> Honor was just another word for dignity and respect. Jake knew that
> sometimes people had to fight back, as when the Borg attacked the
> fleet on their way to capture Earth. But sometimes honor was better
> served by turning away. **The Selay and the Anticans had been denied
> membership in the Federation because they could not settle their
> differences.** There was no honor in that.

Later still, we see an Antican serving aboard the USS Atlas in [TNG: Lost Souls](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2920815-lost-souls?from_search=true) (set some 10 years after the end of the DS9), suggesting that they have attained Federation Membership, the usual pre-condition of which is peace with their neighbours.

Comment: So it would seem that initially it didn't work out... Do you think the fact that there is an Antican later in the series is an indication that they achieved peace, that the federation took sides, or that the federation simply accepted both of them as warring nations. The latter seems unlikely.

Comment: @JMFB - My understanding is that since Fed Membership results in a mutual defence pact, in order to gain Fed Membership, you need to be at peace with your neighbours. My guess is that the Anticans were point-blank told that they needed to sue for peace or no membership.

Comment: Defence not Defense? Are you British?

Comment: @JMFB - Yes. And that's the correct spelling.

Comment: Ha, Ha, LOL. Correct? Websters: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/defense  Good old British Oxford Dictionary: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/defense

Comment: *"Later still, we see an Antican serving aboard the USS Atlas in TNG: Lost Souls (set some 10 years after the end of the DS9), suggesting that they have attained Federation Membership"* We occasionally see a few Ferengi in Starfleet uniforms. Does that mean Ferenginar joined the Federation at some point? I don't see anything that even implies that occurred.

Answer (score 0):

We do not know.

Neither species received much attention after that one episode, although Anticans were occasionally seen in the background.

TNG season 1 had a number of issues, not surprising as they were restarting the series after nearly 2 decades on the shelf and there were various experiments with characters, plot arcs and especially writers. Mostly sorted by season 2.

Comment: Yes I am rewatching the first season right now. There's A LOT of issues with it.